# Django prefetch_related from foreignkey with manytomanyfield not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql

For example, in Django 1.8:

```
class A(models.Model):
    x = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class B(models.Model):
    y = models.ManyToManyField(A)

class C(models.Model):
    z = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

In this scenario, `C.objects.all().prefetch_related('z__b_set')` doesn't work.

Is there a way to prefetch the information I need for `c[0].z.b_set.all()` to work without an extra query?

Comment: Try [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: That would result in a `FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'b_set'.`

Comment: Sorry, I always mix up the two and I didn't even rechecked the documentation before posting. Select_related is to retrieve a single associated object, not a set. Anyway, when you say that prefetch_related doesn't work… can you elaborate a little ? What is happening and what were you expecting ?

Comment: `C.objects.all().prefetch_related('z__b_set')` doesn't change the query like it should. The query string (`str(queryset.query)`) remains exactly the same as `C.objects.all()`.

Comment: what about `C.objects.all().select_related('z').prefetch_related('z__b_set')`?

Comment: That would add `z` to the query as a `LEFT JOIN`, however the `b_set` still isn't included in the query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to follow the first part of the relationship (`C.z`'s `ForeignKey`) in one batch:

```
C.objects.all().select_related('z').prefetch_related('z__b_set')
```

The [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) part, however, will be done in at least two queries, as stated in the docs:

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related. It also supports prefetching of GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey.

Comment: You are right, `str(queryset.query)` isn't the correct way to validate. Still having my problem sadly. `C.z.b_set.get(id=1)` still makes a new query.

Comment: And `C.z.b_set.all()` doesn't! Guess I have to filter it out in python.

Comment: What does `C.z.b_set.get(id=1)` mean? Is it somehow `cs = C.objects.all().select_related('z').prefetch_related('z__b_set'); cs[0].z.b_set.get(id=1)` ??

Comment: `C.z.b_set.get(id=1)` just means i want the B from the set that has id 1. And that adds a query. If I want to filter without using a query, i need to use all() because that's prefetched and then filter in python. Thanks for all the help Mathias :)

Comment: This worked, but seems it does not work any more when upgrading from Django 1.11.x to Django 2.x.

Comment: @Joseph I guess this answer from five years ago can be a bit outdated; but I didn't tried Django 2 yet to update it. If you figure it out, it could be helpful to add this as an answer of your own.

Comment: Didn't figure it out yet heh. Thanks anyway @301_Moved_Permanently.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly set the related_name in B and migrate:

```
class B(models.Model):
    y = models.ManyToManyField(A, related_name="bs")
```

Comment: Nice idea but renaming things doesn't change any functionality.

Comment: I had a similar problem with many to many relationships after upgrading to 1.8 and defining related_name fixed it. I thought it might help in your case too :)