# Django - Pre-fetching ForeignKeys for M2M set

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719359/django-prefetch-related-from-foreignkey-with-manytomanyfield-not-working) which is the reverse (pre-fetching M2M set for foreignkey) - but how can I prefetch the ForeignKeys for a M2M set (as well pre-fetching the initial M2M set)?

E.g. I have the following objects: `Genre`, `Book`, and `Author`. A `Book` can only have one `Author`. A `Genre` can have many `Book`s (and vice versa)

On my `Genre` Detail page, I would like to prefetch and list all the `Book`s (M2M set) as well as prefetch all the `Author`s for each `Book` (ForeignKey).

None of the following seem to work:

```
Genre.objects.all().prefetch_related("book_set", "book_set__author")

Genre.objects.all().prefetch_related("book_set").select_related("book_set__author")

Genre.objects.all().prefetch_related("book_set").select_related("author")
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, `Genre.objects.all().prefetch_related("book_set", "book_set__author")` seems to work!